# Adding watermak to image in WP7

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, watermark

I am trying to make a watermark application and I need to add text to image and I found this tutorial but I am new to WP7 and can anyone say me how to use this?

This is what the code I got it from [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/broux/archive/2011/02/08/silverlight-how-to-watermark-a-writeablebitmapimage-with-a-text.aspx):

```
public static class WriteableBitmapEx
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a watermark on the specified image
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">The image to create the watermark from</param>
    /// <param name="watermark">The text to watermark</param>
    /// <param name="color">The color - default is White</param>
    /// <param name="fontSize">The font size - default is 50</param>
    /// <param name="opacity">The opacity - default is 0.25</param>
    /// <param name="hasDropShadow">Specifies if a drop shadow effect must be added - default is true</param>
    /// <returns>The watermarked image</returns>
    public static WriteableBitmap Watermark(this WriteableBitmap input, string watermark, Color color = default(Color), double fontSize = 50, double opacity = 0.25, bool hasDropShadow = true)
    {
        var watermarked = GetTextBitmap(watermark, fontSize, color == default(Color) ? Colors.White : color, opacity, hasDropShadow);

        var width = watermarked.PixelWidth;
        var height = watermarked.PixelHeight;

        var result = input.Clone();

        var position = new Rect(input.PixelWidth - width - 20 /* right margin */, input.PixelHeight - height, width, height);
        result.Blit(position, watermarked, new Rect(0, 0, width, height));

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a WriteableBitmap from a text
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text"></param>
    /// <param name="fontSize"></param>
    /// <param name="color"></param>
    /// <param name="opacity"></param>
    /// <param name="hasDropShadow"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static WriteableBitmap GetTextBitmap(string text, double fontSize, Color color, double opacity, bool hasDropShadow)
    {
        TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
        txt.Text = text;
        txt.FontSize = fontSize;
        txt.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(color);
        txt.Opacity = opacity;

        if (hasDropShadow) txt.Effect = new DropShadowEffect();

        WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)txt.ActualWidth, (int)txt.ActualHeight);
        bitmap.Render(txt, null);

        bitmap.Invalidate();

        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

If I add to module then I'm getting errors as shown below:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Frankly speaking I would like to know how to use this but I don't know how to implement this :(

Answer (score 3):

This looks pretty straightforward:  **edit: no it wasn't. It was a rabbit hole**

1. Make sure your project includes the WriteableBitmap extension from codeplex (or use NuGet to add it to your project):  http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/
2. Get a BitmapImage from somewhere. (let's assume it is called originalBitmap)
3. Convert it to a WriteableBitmap.

   `var myWritableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(originalBitmap);`
4. Call the method:

   `var watermarkBitmap = WriteableBitmapEx.Watermark(myWriteableBitmap, "The Watermark");`
5. Do what you need to with the watermarked image (save it, display it, whatever).

**edit: A couple of modifications.**

1. Remove the line `if (hasDropShadow) txt.Effect = new DropShadowEffect();`, which is not supported in WP7.
2. In the Watermark method, change this line:

   ```
   var position = new Rect(input.PixelWidth - width - 20 /* right margin */, input.PixelHeight - height, width, height);
   ```

to:

```
    var position = new Rect(20, input.PixelHeight - height, width, height);
```

Then you should be set up to do the following (*caveat emptor - this is not production code.  This is slapdash code meant to help you along the way.  May you be spared a thousand lifetimes of pain if you use this in production code*):

XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="StackOWP7.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="72"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="72"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Image x:Name="picture" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Choose Picture" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Watermark Picture" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

and in the CodeBehind:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var task = new PhotoChooserTask();

        task.Completed += (s, arg) =>
                              {
                                  if(arg.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
                                  {
                                      var bm = new BitmapImage(new Uri(arg.OriginalFileName));
                                      picture.Source = bm;
                                  }
                              };
        task.Show();

    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var wb = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapSource) picture.Source);

        var watermarkedImage = wb.Watermark("watermark", Colors.White, fontSize:50, opacity:.8, hasDropShadow:false);

        picture.Source = watermarkedImage;

    }
```

Comment: @Robaticus-Thanks for your reply and I would like to know that should I add the above code in my question public static class WriteableBitmapEx
{} to the class or to the module?

Comment: @Robaticus-I'm getting errors If I add the above code to module and unable to figure it out as I have updated my question with the error screenshots

Comment: It looks like the class you have uses features that are not supported on the version of Silverlight used by Windows Phone 7.  I'll try to take a look this evening when I'm at a computer that has the SDK installed.

Comment: I hope this example helps you out.  I learned a lot by going through this.